# start_data, end_data and similar fields in vm_area_struct: vm_start, vm_end

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

In mm_struct there are fields that indicate range of data region: start_data, end_data.
And in vm_area_struct of the data region there are also fields that indicate range of this region: vm_start, vm_end.

How do they correspond to each other?
Why there are no bss_start, bss_end fields in mm_struct?

Comment: can you give some context to your question?

Comment: In process memory there are regions: code, data, bss, heap, stack,...

Each of these regions is described in vm_area_struct. There are fields vm_start, vm_end that indicates where each region starts and ends in memory.

But also in mm_struct there are fields like start_data, end_data, start_code, end_code that looks like describing the same thing. Why there are fields that looks like doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

`mm_struct` refers to the whole process and `vm_area_struct` refers to the memory region. A process consists of many memory regions.

> Why there are no bss_start, bss_end fields in mm_struct?

Since mm_struct refers to a whole process not to a specific section of process.

The number of sections and regions in a process are **not** same. Memory regions may be hundreds.

Comment: Yes, mm_struct refers to the whole process, but it has fields like start_code that refers to the memory region (which also has its own struct like vm_area_struct).

My question is: do these fields indicates the same thing? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: @user2818904 The variable of the type `vm_area_struct` refers to the first region `mm_struct`.

Comment: @user2818904 they should refer to the same thing

Comment: Why this is doubled in these structures?

Comment: Actually they are not doubled. `mm_struct` deals with process and 'vm_area_struct' deals with regions. From a process point of view start/end of code/data are its information. And from a regions point of view these are also information. Also the number of sections and regions in a process are not same. Memory regions may be hundreds.